# Chrome 3d Transform flickering

Tags: google-chrome, css

Can anyone fix this flickering issue in Chrome? It works fine in Safari:

http://codepen.io/SequenceLabs/pen/dapxg

I've tried various combinations of `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` but with no joy.